# set white list in python tesserocr pkg

Tags: python, tesseract, whitelist

I have create a config file in tessdata to set the white list. And I also know how to use it in command line shell. But I don't know how to use it in python with tesserocr package. The function [tesserocr.image_to_text()](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/tesserocr.pyx#L2362) seems no parameters for white list.

Comment: Please provide minimal complete example of the problem.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko The wording is a bit rough, but I don't think this question needs a [MCVE] - OP is asking how to create a white list in the Python package, `tesserocr`, since they know it is possible without Python.

Comment: @kabanus thanks, it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that [image_to_text](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/tesserocr.pyx#L2362) doesn't accept white list parameter, please use `SetVariable` for that, see the solution of the setting white list over the tesseroct base api below:

```
api = tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI()
api.ReadConfigFile('digits')
# Consider having string with the white list chars in the config_file, for instance: "0123456789"
while_list = open(config_file_path).read()
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", while_list)
```